# error with spotipy authentication, error 401

Tags: python, api, authentication, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to make a program that reads the songs from a website and when it's about to finish the one that's playing, start the next one, but I'm having a lot of problems with spotipy authentication, at first it worked, but for some reason now it doesn't

I think the tokens expire or something, or I don't know if once you remove the spotify application it won't let you put it back

```
 *****emphasized text***

from email import message
import imp
import json
import tkinter
from turtle import title
import spotipy
import webbrowser
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
import psycopg2
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import threading
import urllib.request
from tkinter import messagebox
import subprocess
#------------------------------------#    

global boolean
boolean = False

conex=sqlite3.connect("BBDD_ID")
cursor=conex.cursor()

#### ------------------------------ SACAMOS LA INFO DE BBDD ------------------------------ ####
#### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ####

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'INFO'")
IDs = cursor.fetchall()

clientID = IDs[0][0]
clientSecret = IDs[0][1]

conex.close()

#### ------------------------------ CONEXION API SPOTIFY ------------------------------ ####
#### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ####

redirectURI = 'http://google.com/'

oauth_object = spotipy.SpotifyOAuth(clientID, clientSecret, redirectURI)


token_dict = oauth_object.get_access_token()

token = token_dict['access_token']

spotifyObject = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

user = spotifyObject.current_user()


#### ------------------------------ FUNCIONES ------------------------------ ####
#### ----------------------------------------------------------------------- ####

def cerrar_app():
    global boolean
    boolean = False

def uri(name):
    searchResults = spotifyObject.search(name,1,0,"track")
    tracks_dict = searchResults['tracks']
    tracks_items = tracks_dict['items']
    song = tracks_items[0]['external_urls']['spotify']
    return song

def playing():
    while(True):
        if(boolean==True):
            data =  pd.DataFrame(spotifyObject.currently_playing())
            restante = (data.loc['duration_ms', 'item']-data.loc['duration_ms', 'progress_ms'])/1000

            if restante < 10 and data.loc['id', 'is_playing'] == True:
                sleep(restante - 4)
                spotifyObject.add_to_queue(uri(buscar_cancion()), device_id=None)
                print("cambiando musica")
                sleep(15)
            else:
               sleep(5)
               print("escanenado a True")
        else:
            sleep(2)
            print("escanenado a false"+str(boolean))

def buscar_cancion():
    
    datos = urllib.request.urlopen('ip').read().decode()
    print(datos)
    return datos

#### -------------------------------- INICIADOR ------------------------------------- ####
#### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ####


def Iniciar():
        global boolean
        boolean=True
        print("Iniciando")
#### ------------------------------ BOB EL CONSTRUCTOR ------------------------------ ####
#### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ####

def visual():
    root = Tk()

    btnPLAY=Button(root, text="Play", width=5, height=1, font=("Nunito"), command=lambda: Iniciar()).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=15, columnspan=1, sticky="e")

    btnSTOP=Button(root, text="Stop", width=5, height=1, font=("Nunito"), command=cerrar_app).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=15, columnspan=1, sticky="e")

    root.mainloop()

#### ----------------------------- Constructor de hilos ----------------------------- ####
#### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ####

hilo1 = threading.Thread(target=visual)

hilo1.start()

playing()**
```

Comment: I recommend to use `http://localhost:8080` as Redirect URI. Then you don't have to copy and paste the URL in your browser anymore.

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear to me if you're trying to have users in this spotipy thing, or if you're just doing everything server-side without user or scope or anything. if you do need a user's authentication though, in this example, you don't give anywhere for a user to actually authenticate with spotify. you skip from initializing the oauth object, and from there you're supposed to

if you're not using authentication, then you're going to want to refresh the token. you already have this in the token_dict, if you print this you'll see that there's another key called 'refresh_token'. this applies if you're doing everything without users or with users, you're going to refresh the token by grabbing the oauth object you made

```
oauth_object.refresh_access_token(token_info['refresh_token'])
```

without refreshing the token, it will expire and you need to make a new one entirely. if you're having trouble making a new one, which i suspect you tried before posting, it could be for a few reasons. one, google.com isn't a valid callback url. you have to specify what callback urls spotify is going to be expecting by adding it to the list in the api dashboard. iirc, the callback url has to match the exact string from what you put in the dashboard and what you put in your program.

i'm not sure if this applies to your program given the lack of users, but i'll tell you this for my program. when you authenticate with spotify, you sign in, and it redirects you to the callback, it gives you an argument in the URL called 'code', you can tell because it says `"?code=<string>"`. this code is what i feed into `spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth` object, inside the `.get_access_token()` method.

so i do `spotipy_object.get_access_token(code)` and that gets me an access token. the only way i know how to get this token is with flask (`code = flask.request.args.get('code')`), which is a little more complicated that what you're making. but see if there's some way for you to grab that code.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6IAGvBZDkE this is a really good three part series on spotipy + flask, so again not relevant to you but this video in particular goes over oauth in a much more approachable way that i very much enjoyed

good luck (: